# Postgres memory usage too low

Tags: linux, memory, postgresql

I have a 400GB `Postgres 9.3.4 DB` running on `Fedora20`, and a few indices per table. I have upped shared buffers to 4GB (the system has 16GB available), set shm in the kernel and set the `effective_cache_size` to 12GB. `work_mem` is 60MB

Then i'm running hundreds of queries per second against the DB for prolonged period. My entire system (with OS) is only using 3GB of RAM and no swap.

`Postgres` isn't really using the RAM it could be using and I'd rather max out my RAM and gain query/index performance if possible.

Am I missing something config wise?

Comment: Are you running 64 bit?

Comment: Yep 64 bit all round

Comment: Anything that won't fit in the shared buffer cache will usually sit in the cache of the OS.  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config-resource.html ... As I understand it, finding out what's in the operating system's cache is difficult. But it sounds like your effective_cache_size is set properly. If it's a dedicated database server, you might even raise it to 15GB or more.

Answer (score 6):

> Postgres isn't really using the RAM it could be using

Actually, it probably is.

PostgreSQL relies on the Linux kernel to cache disk blocks. That's what `effective_cache_size` is about - it's telling PostgreSQL what kind of cache size it can *expect the kernel to maintain*.

Run:

```
free -m
```

You'll probably see almost all RAM in use as buffers/cache. Which is exactly what you want.

Comment: I think you are right: total: 15G, free 173M, cached:10G, buffers:63M, shared:4.7G