# How can Postgresql use more of the total RAM?

Tags: postgresql, linux, memory

I'm trying to undertstand how Postgresql's (v9.1) memory usage relate to the overall Linux memory.

When I look at htop, I see that the system is using about 60GB out of a total of 256GB RAM. That seems a bit of a waste to me. The system is primarily running a large 700GB postgresql database and some webserver processes (nginx, tomcat, etc). Now, I understand that linux doesn't waste memory and that the rest of the 256-60 GB RAM is used for buffers/cache, and that the OS is good at managing this for the different applications. But I don't know exactly how those buffers/cache can benefit different apps and I want to make sure Postgresql gets more of the share.

Moreover, and correct me if I'm wrong, I have the impression that even if I were to tune Postgresql settings to use more RAM, the application will never be able to use more RAM than what is defined by the shmmax kernel parameter.

I have tried a few Postgresql tuning scripts and followed their recommendations, with regards to e.g. shared_buffers, while also keeping an eye on the logs. I can configure it to use more memory, so that htop shows more memory usage but this led me to the following question:

How can Postgresql use more of the available RAM, i.e. the RAM that is currently used for buffers/cache, without also crippling the web processes?

Comment: There is a problem where sometimes Postgresql gets  slow and even unresponsive. The OS is running fine with regards to memory, cpu, i/o, network etc. 9.1 is indeed old but upgrading is kind of beyond my control, unfortunately.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgres memory usage too low](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62330/postgres-memory-usage-too-low)

Comment: If you want to improve performance and make more use of the available RAM, upgrade to a current version of Postgres. With the release of Postgres 13 imminent, you are almost 9 major versions behind, and support for 9.1 ended almost 4 years ago.

Comment: @Colin'tHart The other question is very helpful and interesting, although it doesn't really answer my concern about how to adjust the database memory while considering other applications. It's difficult to just answer yes/no if that question answers my problem. About upgrading the version, totally agree, but that is currenly not possible (company decision, not mine). Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have set yourself up for a difficult task by running your HTTP server, application server, and database server on the same machine.

On a dedicated database server it is common to allocate 80% to 90% of available RAM to Postgres. Since Postgres uses a single shared memory segment, you'd set `shmmax` to exceed that value<sup>1</sup>, then carve out various memory areas, particularly `shared_buffers` and `work_mem`, according to the demands of your workload and Postgres configuration parameters.

Since you make Postgres share server resources with other consumers, you will need to figure out how much memory you can give Postgres without starving the other guys to death. This becomes especially tricky as the memory pressure from all three (HTTP server, Java container, and Postgres) will grow *simultaneously* as the workload increases. Observe how much memory is consumed by everything else except Postgres during peak load and allocate 90% of what's left to Postgres, the follow the logic described earlier to determine [the minimally acceptable] `shmmax`.

Ideally, you'd want to give Postgres a dedicated machine, even with lesser specs, to make your tuning job significantly easier. Also, upgrade.

---

1 - It doesn't hurt to set `shmmax` to a very large value, Postgres will not request more than dictated by its configuration parameters.

Comment: Am I correct that shmmax is not as relevant for Postgresql versions from 9.3 and later? (Yes OP is using 9.1)

Comment: @user202323 what makes you think so?

Comment: Version 9.2 and earlier is using SYSV IPC shared memory which requires SHMMAX, while 9.3+ is using POSIX IPC. But I'm not expert on this, which is why I'm asking. src: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/kernel-resources.html

Comment: This part: "Postgres uses a single shared memory segment", doesn't apply anymore (apparently Postgres uses `mmap` by default now), but the rest still seems ok to me.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL will use as much of the file system cache as it can, so your only problem is to limit the resources used by the competing applications.

If that cannot be done by configuring them appropriately, you could make use of Linux control groups:

Create a control group where `memory.limit_in_bytes` is limited and place your web server and application server into this control group. That limits the memory that can be used by those applications collectively, **including the file system cache**.

Comment: Is there any difference in how PostgreSQL uses the file system cache and how it would use more "dedicated" memory? Also, interesting about using control group. I know about them but it had not occured to me to use it in this context.

Comment: That's what control groups are made for. PostgreSQL's use of the file system cache is less efficient than shared buffers (it requires a kernel system call), but some workloads have problems with large shared buffers. You should experiment with different settings of `shared_buffers` to find the sweet spot. But the first measure before you do all that is upgrade, since using 9.1 is criminally negligent.